# Identifying a plant with pink and white flowers which grow in clusters

Tags: identification, flowers, hydrangea

I was wondering if anyone could help me identify the plant with the pink flowers in the photo below. This photo was taken roughly a week ago in western Shanghai, China, at a public park.

Many thanks in advance!

(Apologies if this is a duplicate, I looked into related/similar questions and did not find one.)

[image]

Comment: For comparison, see [this related Q/A](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33890/hydrangea-flowers-not-blooming-as-expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [*hydrangea macrophylla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrangea_macrophylla), of the [“lacecap”](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/shrubs/hydrangea/lacecap-hydrangea-care.htm) type.

While the “mop head” shows just the larger type of flowers with decorative sepals, the lacecaps have flowers with sepals at the perimeter of the corymb only, and the less showy flowers at the center.